# open() return new file descriptor posix

Tags: posix, c++, system-calls, error-handling

I have to set the return values for open() in posix. How do I return "the new file descriptor" as it is said in the Linux man pages:

> RETURN VALUE
>
> ```
>  open(), openat(), and creat() return the new file descriptor, or -1
>  if an error occurred (in which case, errno is set appropriately).
> ```

Edit: Thanks goldilocks! I was not looking in the right direction. What I am doing is that I am correcting the return value of this system call. Apparently it returns something wrong.

Comment: Maybe you should clarify what you are doing: implementing an operating system?!?  Generally you *don't* set return values for system calls, they are set by the system.

Comment: What return value of `open()` do you get of which you think it is wrong?

Comment: The return value is the error number of the message. I am thinking of what I've read in the man pages that there should be two returns. One without error and one with error, so I can set the errno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open a file, you use a construct like the following:

```
int fd;
if ((fd = open(path, flags)) < 0) {
    /* An error occurred, the reason is in errno */
    int _errno = errno; /* Save errno value */
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed opening file '%s': %s\n", path, strerror(_errno));
    return;
}
/* The file was successfully opened */
```

So, you have only one return value, which normally is the file descriptor. If it is `-1`, it indicates that an error has occurred. The error that occurred is stored in the `errno` variable (which you get by including `errno.h` into your source file).